# Can we run Non-browser functionalities through Grid

Tags: java, sql, selenium, selenium-grid

I have Excel related Test cases which don't interact with Browser , but it will use the SQL in background and run the queries. Can I use the Grid functionality for the non browser related test cases like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make use of Selenium Grid functionality to invoke functionalities that reside on a remote node via a Servlet call which you would inject into the node.
You would first resort to the approach I explained in [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/where-did-my-test-run/) blog post of mine to find out to which node was the test routed to and then use the approach explained in the [Selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid) to route calls to the servlet to invoke such remote node specific calls.

But I would like to understand  why do you want to do this ? Your excel related tests are still going to be run in the local JVM ( the JVM wherein your tests were being spun off), and so the usage of SQL for running queries is also going to be limited to the local JVM and has nothing to do with the Selenium Grid or the nodes.